# How to convert xpath Element to XML?

Tags: python, xpath

I am using python xpath and I need to convert `Element` to XML.

`<Element {http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1}application at 0x16568142d48>`

I discovered methods with `dir`, and did not found any proper method.

```
['__bool__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_init', 'addnext', 'addprevious', 'append', 'attrib', 'base', 'clear', 'cssselect', 'extend', 'find', 'findall', 'findtext', 'get', 'getchildren', 'getiterator', 'getnext', 'getparent', 'getprevious', 'getroottree', 'index', 'insert', 'items', 'iter', 'iterancestors', 'iterchildren', 'iterdescendants', 'iterfind', 'itersiblings', 'itertext', 'keys', 'makeelement', 'nsmap', 'prefix', 'remove', 'replace', 'set', 'sourceline', 'tag', 'tail', 'text', 'values', 'xpath']
```

App:

afile.xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<applications >
  <application >
      <journalNumber > 1 < /journalNumber >
   </application >
   <application >
      <journalNumber > 2</journalNumber>
   </application >
</applications >
```

app:

```
    etxml = etree.parse(afile)
    root = etxml.getroot()

    value = root.xpath("//*[local-name() = '{0}']".format("application"))
```

Comment: share the crucial enclosing html/xml fragment raw presentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
etxml = etree.parse(afile)
root = etxml.getroot()

value = root.xpath("//*[local-name() = '{0}']".format("application"))

etree.tostring(value)
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please explain (or refer me to a link explaining) how the `format("application")` method works here? If find it confusing and my searches didn't come up with anything.

Comment: No, I'm familiar with that (though I usually use f-strings); I just don't understand the mechanism of using an xml tag name (`"application"`, in this case) as a replacement string for all `local-name()`s to get you to the expected output.

Comment: That was the OP's original line of code, I only quoted it, I did not question it, because *how* he gets an element from the tree is irrelevant to the question that was asked.

Comment: `"//*[local-name() = '{0}']".format("application")` results in `"//*[local-name() = 'application']`, which is valid XPath. It's not necessarily what I would do, and it's and indication that the OP's XML document contains namespaces and that he doesn't know how to handle them properly, but as I said, that's besides the point.